# Запись текста от пользователя в переменную

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

попытался написать бота сам, но не получилось следующее:
не смог сделать запись д/з, которое присылает пользователь в переменную и отправку д/з по запросу
не смог разделить получение и отправку д/з ботом, сделал через elif
сам бот https://github.com/Alchel007/h-w-bot/blob/main/MAIN!!!.py
бот написан на telebot
заранее благодарю
получение д/з

```
    elif message.text == 'Алг. Профиль':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Главное меню')
            markup.add(btn1)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправьте д/з в формате текста')
```

отправка д/з

```
    elif message.text == 'Алг. Профиль.':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Главное меню')
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         'Д/З:',
                         reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В библиотеке Telebot существует прекрасная функция:

```
.register_next_step_handler
```

Нужна она для получения значения от пользователя и ее последовательной передачи в функцию

В твоем случае нужно:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, и во втором параметре передай имя нужной функции)
```

Готовый код:

```
elif message.text == 'Алг. Профиль':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Главное меню')
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправьте д/з в формате текста')
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, gowritedz)

def gowritedz(message):
    with open('dzalgebra.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'{message.text}\n')
```

Тут в коде получается текст от пользователя и записывается в .txt файл. Далее в нужной функции просто считываешь текст из файла и выводишь пользователю.
Всё.

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему изучив sqlite3

```
    def dz_add(dz, lesson):
        chat_id = dz.chat.id
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Д/З')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        if dz.text == ' Главное меню':
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "выберите раздел", reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            dz_add_bd(dz=dz.text, lesson=lesson)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "Д/з добавлено", )
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "выберите раздел", reply_markup=markup)
    
    
    def dz_add_bd(dz, lesson):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(database="db.sqlite")
    
        cur = conn.cursor()
        try:
            cur.execute("""
                    create table dz_table
                    (
                    id          INTEGER not null
                        constraint dz_table_pk
                            primary key,
                    name_lesson varchar,
                    dz          TEXT
                    );
                    """)
            conn.commit()
        except:
            pass
    
        if cur.execute(f"select dz from dz_table where name_lesson = '{lesson}'").fetchone():
            cur.execute(f"update dz_table set dz = '{dz}' where name_lesson = '{lesson}' ")
        else:
            cur.execute((f'INSERT INTO dz_table (name_lesson, dz) VALUES  ("{lesson}", "{dz}")'))
        conn.commit()
    
    
    def dz_get(lesson):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(database="db.sqlite")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        less = lesson[0:-1]
        dz = cur.execute(f"select dz from dz_table where name_lesson = '{less}'").fetchone()
        if dz is None:
            return "Домашнего задания не задано"
        else:
            return dz[0]
```